# Given a measure $\lambda$, show that $\lambda = 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that if $\lambda$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $L^n$ and $\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\lambda(B(x, r))}{r^{n}} = 0$ for every $ x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ then $\lambda = 0$.

If I could show that $L^n=0$ then $\lambda=0$ from being absolutely continuous w.r.t $L^n$. I am thinking that the Radon-Nikodym theorem would be helpful, as $\lambda<<L^n$, then we can find $h\geq 0$ such that $\lambda(\mathbb{R}^n)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} h $ $ dL^n$. However, I can't seem to use it. Any ideas? Try not to give full solutions, thank you.

Comment: Try applying the Lebesgue differentiation theorem to the function $h$ to show it is zero almost everywhere.

Comment: The translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure will be useful.

Comment: Using the Lebesgue differentiation theorem we are looking at $\lim_{r\to 0}|B(0,r)|^{-1} \int_{B(0,r)}h$, by the translational invariance of the Lebesgue measure. Now, we should try to relate this to our limit condition.

Comment: Any small hints moving forward, I am stuck.

Comment: Are you sure the original question has $\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\lambda(B(x,r))}{r^{-n}}=0$ and not $\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\lambda(B(x,r))}{r^{n}}=0$? I missed the minus sign when I first read it.

Comment: I fixed it, thank you

Comment: Okay, so in that case, the limit in the Lebesgue differentiation theorem should look very similar to the limit in the problem statement (in fact they only differ by a constant). What does the Lebesgue differentiation theorem tell you about the value of that limit?

Comment: I think that means $h=0$ $a.e$.

Comment: So based on what you found from the Radon-Nikodym theorem, that should tell you $\lambda=0$.

Comment: I got it now, thanks.

Comment: Is this from Mattila?